# "Quam" as relative pronoun or conjunction?

Tags: grammar-identification, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

In LLpsI 38:106:

> Italia, ..., longō cursū abs tē dīviditur: prius circum Siciliam tibi nāvigandum est ***quam*** in illā terrā urbem condere poteris.

What is the role of ***quam*** here?
If it is relative, what does it mean in its clause?

(btw. what is the noun for the gerundive ***nāvigandum*** here?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *quam* is a conjunction, working with the comparative *prius*. Taken together, they are equivalent to the English conjunction "before." It's perhaps easier to see the meaning if we reorder the elements: *Siciliam tibi navigandum est prius quam urbem condere poteris*.

*Navigandum est* is neuter singular because it is an impersonal gerundive ([A&G 500](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/gerund-and-gerundive)). That is, *navigandum* is not a true passive modifying any head noun. The action itself is obligatory. This usage is analogous to the impersonal "passive" with intransitive verbs in the indicative: ventum est, itur, pugnatur. However, even transitive verbs can be impersonal in the gerundive: *nunc est bibendum* ("now it's time to drink").

Comment: What is the difference between "prius" = "before" and  "prius" "quam" (written, annoyingly, as two words) = "before"?

Comment: @tony "prius" by itself is an adverb. "prius" plus "quam" is a conjunction. "Jim arrived earlier [in the day]" vs. "Jim arrived earlier than Bob [arrived]".